# Treat all unhandled angularjs states/urls as regular links

Tags: angularjs

I would like to treat all url paths as regular links, instead of having angularjs handling them, unless they are explicitly listed in the angular.module.config() as a state/url.

So, say I have legacy web pages at /old and /old2 and new angularjs pages at /new and /new2. I would like /old and old2 to be treated as new, full browser page requests rather than being handled by angularjs.

I've tried html5Mode() rewriteLinks=false like this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    rewriteLinks: false
});
```

But then no links are handled by angularjs at all. It would be nice if it could be smart enough to avoid having to include special coding for each case.

Thanks,

Comment: isn't it enough to just remove the hash-bang (`/#!/`) from URL to make it independent? e.g. `website.com/#!/angular-page` , `website.com/not-angular-page.html`

Comment: Not when you're using html5mode and angularjs links look just like regular pages ie. /angular-page